# running parallel code on PC

Tags: fortran, gfortran, hpc, pbs

I have fortran code that has been parallelized with OpenMP. I want to test my code on my PC before running on HPC. My PC has double core CPU and I work on Linux-mint. I installed gfortranmultilib and this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
### Job name
#PBS -N pme
### Keep Output and Error
#PBS -j eo
### Specify the number of nodes and thread (ppn) for your job.
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=2
### Switch to the working directory;
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
### Run:
OMP_NUM_THREADS=$PBS_NUM_PPN
export  OMP_NUM_THREADS
ulimit -s unlimited
./a.out

echo 'done'
```

What should I do more to run my code?

OK, I changed script as suggested in answers:

```
#!/bin/bash
### Switch to the working directory;
cd Desktop/test
### Run:
OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
export  OMP_NUM_THREADS
ulimit -s unlimited
./a.out

echo 'done'
```

my code and its executable file are in folder test on Desktop, so:

```
cd Desktop/test
```

is this correct?

then I compile my simple code:

```
  implicit none
  !$OMP PARALLEL
  write(6,*)'hi'
  !$OMP END PARALLEL
  end
```

by command:

```
gfortran -fopenmp test.f
```

and then run by:

```
./a.out
```

but only one "hi" is printed as output. What should I do?
(and a question about this site: in situation like this I should edit my post or just add a comment?)

Comment: are the shell variables PBS_O_WORKDIR and PBS_NUM_PPN correctly defined ? Is the executable program a.out really located in $PBS_O_WORKDIR ? Notice that PBS_NUM_PPN must be equal to 2 (number of cores). If yes for each question then all seems OK !

Comment: How can I find the location of a.out? And if the location is not $PBS_O_WORKDIR how should I change the script? I am sorry for simple questions, this is the first time I work with hpc and openmp and even fortran!

Comment: Sorry but if you don't know where to find your executable program (a.out), then I can't help you.

Comment: I see a.out in my folder but when you say is a.out really located in $PBS_O_WORKDIR I think for parallel running a.out should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need and probably don't want to use the script on your PC. Not even to learn how to use such a script, because these scripts are too much connected to the specifics of each supercomputer.

I use several supercomputers/clusters and I cannot just reuse the script from one at the other, because they are so much different.

On your PC you should just do:

1. optional, it is probably the default

   ```
   export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
   ```

to set the number of OpenMP threads to 2. Adjust if you need some other number.

2. cd to the working directory

   ```
   cd my_working_directory
   ```

Your working directory is the directory where you have the required data or where the executable resides. In your case it seems to be the directory where `a.out` is.

3. run the damn thing

   ```
   ulimit -s unlimited
   ./a.out
   ```

That's it.

You can also store the standard output and error output to a file

```
    ./out > out.txt 2> err.txt
```

to mimic the supercomputer behaviour.

---

The PBS variables are only set when you run the script using `qsub`. You probably don't have that on your PC and you probably don't want to have it either.

`$PBS_O_WORKDIR` is the directory where you run the `qsub` command, unless you set it differently by other means.

`$PBS_NUM_PPN` is the number you indicated in `#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=2`. The queue system reads that and sets this variable for you.

Answer (score 2):

The script you posted is for Portable Batch System (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System) queue system. That means, that the job you want to run on the HPC infrastructure has to go first into the queue system and when the resources are available the job will run on the system.

Some of the commands (those starting with #PBS) are specific commands for this queue system. Among these commands, some allow the user to indicate the application process hierarchy (i.e. number of processes and threads). Also, keep in mind that since all the PBS commands start by # they are ignored by regular shell script execution. In the case you presented, that is given by

```
### Specify the number of nodes and thread (ppn) for your job.
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=2
```

which as the comment indicates it should tell the queue system that you want to run 1 process and each process will have 2 threads. The queue system is likely to pass these parameters to the process launcher (srun/mpirun/aprun/... for MPI apps in addition to OMP_NUM_THREADS for OpenMP apps).

If you want to run this job on a computer that does not have PBS queue, you should be aware at least of two things.

1) The following command

```
### Switch to the working directory;
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
```

will be translated into "cd" because the environment variable PBS_O_WORKDIR is only defined within the PBS job context. So, you should change this command (or execute another cd command just before the execution) in order to fix where you want to run the job.

2) Similarly for PBS_NUM_PPN environment variable,

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=$PBS_NUM_PPN
export  OMP_NUM_THREADS
```

this variable won't be defined if you don't run this within a PBS job context, so you should set OMP_NUM_THREADS to the value you want (2, according to your question) manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your linux box environment to be like an HPC login node. You can do the following

- Make sure that your compiler supports OpenMP, test a simple hello world program with OpenMP flags
- Install OpenMPI on your system from your favourite package manager or download the source/binary from the website ([OpenMPI Download](http://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.10/))
- I would not recommend installing cluster manager like Slurm for your experiments

After you are done, you can execute your MPI programs through the mpirun wrapper

```
mpirun -n <no_of_cores> <executable>
```

EDIT:

This is assuming that you are running this only MPI. Note that OpenMP utilizes the cores as well. If you are running MPI+OpenMP - `n*OMP_NUM_THREADS=cores` on a single node.

Comment: Be careful when combining MPI+OpenMP because <no_of_cores> should be read as <no_of_MPI_processes>.